# cakephp Model validation error message not displaying in hasOne association

Tags: php, model, cakephp-3.0

i want to do `model` validation with `association` in a single form. i have two tables `users`(parent table) and `user_details`(child table).now model validation is working for users table only.i want it for userDetails table also. relation between them is `hasOne`.

validation working for only users table because i have created newEntity for users table only.

usersController.php (controller code)

```
 public function add() {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        $userDetail = $this->UserDetails->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $userDetail = $this->UserDetails->patchEntity($userDetail, $this->request->getData());
                $userDetail->user_id = $user->id;
                if ($this->UserDetails->save($userDetail)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user','userDetail'));
    }
```

UsersTable.php (parent model)

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
        $validator
                ->integer('id')
                ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
                ->email('email')
                ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('email');


        $validator
                ->scalar('mobile')
                ->maxLength('mobile', 10,'Maximum length should be 10 digits')
                ->minLength('mobile', 10,'Minimum length should be 10 digits')
                ->requirePresence('mobile', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('mobile');

        $validator
                ->scalar('password')
                ->maxLength('password', 20,'Minimum length should be 20 digits')
                ->minLength('password', 4,'Minimum length should be 4 digits')
                ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('password');


        return $validator;
    }
```

UserDetailsTable.php (child model)

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('name')
            ->maxLength('name', 50)
            ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('name');

        $validator
            ->scalar('pin')
            ->maxLength('pin', 6)
            ->requirePresence('pin', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('pin');

        $validator
            ->scalar('address')
            ->maxLength('address', 4294967295)
            ->requirePresence('address', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('address');

        return $validator;
    }
```

add.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add'], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'add-user']); ?>

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name <label class="text-danger">*</label></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->control('user_detail.name', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name', 'placeholder' => 'Name', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => false]); ?>
                </div>
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email <label class="text-danger">*</label></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->control('email', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'Email', 'type' => 'email', 'label' => false]); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mobile <label class="text-danger">*</label></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->control('mobile', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'mobile', 'placeholder' => 'Mobile', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => false]); ?>
                </div>
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Password <label class="text-danger">*</label></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->control('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password', 'placeholder' => 'Password', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => false]); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Generate</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="state" class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->select('user_detail.state', ['Odisha', 'Hyderbad'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'state', 'label' => false]); ?>

                </div>
                <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->select('user_detail.city', ['Bhubaneswar', 'Cuttack'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'city', 'label' => false]); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->control('user_detail.address', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'address', 'type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => 2, 'label' => false]); ?>
                </div>
                <label for="pin" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pin</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <?= $this->Form->control('user_detail.pin', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'pin', 'placeholder' => 'Pin', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => false]); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    <?= $this->Form->control('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'submit', 'type' => 'submit', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'templates' => ['submitContainer' => '{{content}}']]); ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

here is the image for reference

[image]

in this image all fields are mandatory
all fields are from users table...only address field is from user_details table.now you can see error message showing for first name field but error message not showing for address field.validation working for address field but don't know why error message is not displaying.

first name from users table and address from user_details table

thanks in advance

Comment: not clear what kind of relationship you have between users and user_details. I guess hasOne. So according to the [**manual**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) (same link provided by ndm in his answer) the input name should be `user_detail.address`

Answer (score 2):

> validation working for only users table because i have created newEntity for users table only.

That has nothing to do with it. The problem is that you are not following the naming conventions properly.

Filenames must match classnames, so it's `UserDetailsTable.php`, not `UserDetails.php`, `UsersTable.php`, not `usersTable.php`, etc.

And the correct property name for a `hasOne` association, is the singular, underscored variant of the association name, so for `UserDetails` that would be `user_detail`, consequently the name for the related form control should be `user_detail.name`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > CakePHP at a Glance > CakePHP Conventions > File and Class Name Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving HasOne Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasone-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > HasOne Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)**

Comment: i have follow all these above links .sorry typing mistake but i am following the naming conventions. i am updating it again.

Comment: i f i changing it to user_detail.name then validation is working but error message is not showing below each field but for user table its showing perfectlty.

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumar That's something that you need to debug further, I have no way to reproduce it, and it's a different issue than the original question. If you can't figure it out, create a new question with some short example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: i have add a screenshot in this question .and i explained briefly about this situation there.please have a look and tell me if any solution

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to patch your details entity with the wrong data (`$this->request->getData()`). But really, there is no need to create, patch and save a separate entity in your `add` function, because the first level of associations will be handled transparently for you. This should work just fine:

```
public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

Or, at least, it should once you correct the field names from the details entity to include "user_detail.", as @ndm said; your HTML above is still showing `$this->Form->control('address',...)` instead of `$this->Form->control('user_detail.address',...)`, though it also includes fields for city and state, which aren't in your screen shot, so it's unclear what your current version might look like.

Comment: i have tried with user_detail.address and user_detail.0.address but nothing is working in user table record inserted but user_details table still blank

Comment: If you `debug($user);` after the `patchEntity` call, what does it look like?

Comment: Maybe also include your `initialize` function from `UsersTable` class, so we can see the association.

Comment: 'email' => 'soubhhbh@yahoo.com',
 'mobile' => '5136563514',
 'password' => 'vhgnvhgfhfh',
 '[new]' => true,
 '[accessible]' => [
  'email' => true,
  'mobile' => true,
  'password' => true,
  'user_status' => true,
  'user_type' => true,
  'created' => true,
  'updated' => true,
  'orders' => true,
  'user_details' => true
 ],
 '[dirty]' => [
  'email' => true,
  'mobile' => true,
  'password' => true,
  'user_detail' => true
 ],
 '[original]' => [],
 '[virtual]' => [],
 '[errors]' => [],
 '[invalid]' => [],
 '[repository]' => 'Users'

Comment: public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');
        $this->loadModel('Users');
        $this->loadModel('UserDetails');
        $this->loadComponent('Custom');
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    }

Comment: Need to see the `initialize` function from the `UsersTable`, not the `UsersController`. There's something weird in your data, though, as the `accessible` list says `user_details`, but the `dirty` list says `user_detail`.

Comment: $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            $userDetail = $this->UserDetails->newEntity($this->request->getData()['user_detail']);
            $user->user_detail = $userDetail;
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } 


finally i got my answer

Comment: This is still more complicated than it needs to be. The `$userDetail` variable should not be needed at all. The fact that it is indicates a problem somewhere else. Maybe in your association definition, maybe in your table class name, maybe in the naming of your fields. Probably some combination of these. All of which are documented in the links provided by @ndm. If you don't care about learning how to get it right, what you have will work for now, but you'll run into the same problems again and again in the future.

Comment: as i told i have tried every thing nothing i working for me ...and naming convention is perfect because i have generated all through cake bake all.